# XML::Twig modify text of multiple elements

Tags: xml, perl, text-parsing

I'm trying to change the text of three elements from a source XML file.

Two of the targets have the same element name (`ifw6:value`), but exist under different headers. The third has a different element name from the first two.

The program executes successfully, but prints the original XML file without modifying anything. Debug statements lead me to believe it's not executing the subroutine mapped in `twig_handlers`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $text1 = "123456789";
my $text2 = "1234567";
my $text3 = "001";

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
     pretty_print => 'indented',
     twig_handlers => {

         text => sub {

             my $targ1_2 = $_->next_elt('ifw6:value');
             my $targ3   = $_->next_elt('ifw4:relationship');

             if ($targ1_2->text eq 'target1') {
                 $targ1_2->set_text($text1);
             }

             if ($targ1_2->text eq 'target2') {
                 $targ1_2->set_text($text2);
             }

             if ($targ3->text eq 'target3') {
                 $targ3->set_text($text3);
             }

             $targ1_2->flush;
             $targ3->flush;
         }
    }
);


$twig->parsefile('text.xml');
$twig->print();
```

#### text.xml

```
<SOAP-ENV>
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ifw:Information>
         <requestHeader>
            <ifw1:id/>
         </requestHeader>
         <ifw4:Miscellaneous>
            <ifw6:MiscVals xsi:type="type1">
               <ifw6:value>target1</ifw6:value>
            </ifw6:MiscVals>
            <ifw6:MiscVals xsi:type="type2">
              <ifw6:Vals xsi:type="type3">
                  <ifw6:value>target2</ifw6:value>
              </ifw6:Vals>
           </ifw6:MiscVals>
              <ifw4:relationship>target3</ifw4:relationship>
           </ifw4:Miscellaneous>
        </ifw:Information>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV>
```

#### desired result

```
<SOAP-ENV>
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ifw:Information>
         <requestHeader>
            <ifw1:id/>
         </requestHeader>
         <ifw4:Miscellaneous>
            <ifw6:MiscVals xsi:type="type1">
               <ifw6:value>123456789</ifw6:value>
            </ifw6:MiscVals>
            <ifw6:MiscVals xsi:type="type2">
              <ifw6:Vals xsi:type="type3">
                  <ifw6:value>1234567</ifw6:value>
              </ifw6:Vals>
           </ifw6:MiscVals>
              <ifw4:relationship>001</ifw4:relationship>
           </ifw4:Miscellaneous>
        </ifw:Information>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV>
```

Comment: Your `text` is looking for elements like `<text>`, not text nodes. In XPath you would use `text()`, but I'm not sure that wil work in `XML::Twig`.

Comment: Search instead for `ifw6:value` and `ifw4:relationship` and modify their text content.

Comment: the proper way is indeed to have `twig_handlers` on named elements, as @Borodin says. To trigger a handler on text you need to use '#TEXT', which is admittedly confusing if you're used to CSS selectors, but this syntax actually predates CSS :--(

Comment: @mirod: Thank you for the confirmation. Of course I should have remembered `#TEXT`, but the code would have to check `$_->parent->tag`, which is more cumbersome. Although, thinking about it, I doubt if a text node is an `XML::Twig::Elt` object, and I'm not in a position to experiment.

Comment: @Borodin a text node *is* an XML::Twig::Elt object. It has to, in order for mixed-content to work. Its tag "name" is `#PCDATA` (or `#CDATA`), although you can't have a handler on `#PCDATA` (IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, but I have no way to test it at present

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(

     pretty_print => 'indented',

     twig_handlers => {

         'ifw6:value' => sub {

             my $text = $_->trimmed_text;

             if ($text eq 'target1') {
                 $_->set_text($text1);
             }
             elsif ($text eq 'target2') {
                 $_->set_text($text2);
             }

             $_->flush;
         },

         'ifw4:relationship' => sub {

             my $text = $_->trimmed_text;

             if ($text eq 'target3') {
                 $_->set_text($text3);
             }

             $_->flush;
         }
    }

);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $text1 = "123456789";
my $text2 = "12345678901011121314151";
my $text3 = "001";

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    twig_handlers => {
        'ifw6:value[string()="target1"]' => sub {
            $_->set_text($text1);
        },
        'ifw6:value[string()="target2"]' => sub {
            $_->set_text($text2);
        },
        'ifw4:relationship[string()="target3"]' => sub {
            $_->set_text($text3);
        }
    }
);

$twig->parsefile('text.xml');
$twig->print();
```

Using flush did weird things for me, I'm not sure if it's entirely needed. I think you desired result target2 replacement is missing some of the string.